# NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.delete(Ljava/lang/Object;)V while upgrading Spring boot from 1.5.3 to 2.1.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I am upgrading the spring boot from 1.5.3 version to 2.1.6 release. I have added below dependencies:

```
classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis')
  {
    exclude group: 'io.lettuce', module: 'lettuce-core'
  } 
compile('redis.clients:jedis:2.9.0')
```

I am getting below error:

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.delete(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at com.aonhewitt.upoint.cache.config.provider.impl.RedisCacheObjectProviderImpl.delete(RedisCacheObjectProviderImpl.java:292)
    at com.aonhewitt.upoint.cache.util.DistributedCacheUtil.deleteCacheKey(DistributedCacheUtil.java:490)
    at com.aonhewitt.upoint.cache.util.DistributedCacheUtil$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$10d7e0fa.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684)
    at com.aonhewitt.upoint.cache.util.DistributedCacheUtil$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$15db3ca8.deleteCacheKey()
    at com.aonhewitt.upoint.portal.configuration.util.ConfigurationParmUtil.manageClntParmKeysInRedis(ConfigurationParmUtil.java:49)
    at com.aonhewitt.portal.configuration.workengine.ConfigurationController.processRequest(ConfigurationController.java:234)
    at com.aonhewitt.portal.configuration.workengine.ConfigurationGateway.processRequest(ConfigurationGateway.java:56)
    at com.aonhewitt.portal.configuration.service.util.ConfigurationInit.load(ConfigurationInit.java:34)
    at com.aonhewitt.upoint.core.ConfigMgrStartUp.init(ConfigMgrStartUp.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitializatio

Comment: Did you try to add commons-pool2 dependency ?

Comment: Yes, still the same error  after adding this dependency compile('org.apache.commons:commons-pool2')

Answer (score 0):

Just check your dependencies and remove old-version spring-data dependency

Answer (score 0):

You have got both the starter-data-redis and jedis-client. Jedis works with spring-data-redis. Or starter-data-redis works by itself. The below combination worked for me:

org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:2.4.8:compile
redis.clients:jedis:jar:3.3.0:compile

Reference link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-tutorial